# how to send response to httpwebrequest for Web scraping

Tags: php, cookies, web-scraping, httpwebrequest, keep-alive

Hello i try to scraping data from web page but here is my problem :
When i connect to the server with `httpwebrequest` server set header to `Connection: Keep-Alive` and then request to load a captcha web page (in real webpage captcha load with `ajax`) then after solved captcha returned answer to the last request and finally load data

```
webpage -> captcha -> Solve -> Back to first web page -> show data
```

[image: Pic of work]

and how i try to do ?

- send request with `webrequest` to web page
- get `cookie` information from `request`
- load `captcha page` and get `catpcha pic`
- `send captcha pic` to other site for `solve` that and `get captcha
  answer`
- send `captcha answer` with `webrequest` and `get cookie and session
  id`
- send `new webrequest` with `cookie and session id` for `load data`

and always -> failed , I thinks that's because for `Connection: Keep-Alive` so how can i solve this problem ?
and also when i try to load page in webbrowse i don't know why but in any browser controle page dosen't load correctly so i can't do work with browser

**Update**
my problem :
how to send answer (post data again) to `httpwebrequest` after `GetResponse()` from that and keep it online (without using from new connection)

Comment: Please try to describe one problem that you can't solve. For instance how to get a connection without the `keep-alive` property. Have a look at [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Ok,Updated! now what do you think ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a problem with `keep-alive` then try to disable it: [HttpWebRequest.KeepAlive Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.keepalive(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.contoso.com");

req.KeepAlive = false;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer however if you understand my problem you know all of my problem is disconnecting from httpwebreq and open an other so i don't thinks that's work , do you think ?